# Capistrano recipe to update gems on server before executing other dependent tasks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, capistrano, bundler

My Capistrano recipe (pretty vanilla) is failing because versions of gems on server don't match what's in the Gemfile (i guess).

How can I fix this? I thought 'bundle update' on server was automatically part of default Cap recipe? ...I must be wrong. If so, how to add?

Background info: System wide RVM installed on the server. But the Cap recipe knows the name of the gemfile which is `ruby-1.9.3@myapp`.

in my deploy.rb as per [RVM's site](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/integration/capistrano/):

```
$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path'])) # Add RVM's lib directory to the load path.
require "rvm/capistrano"                  # Load RVM's capistrano plugin.
set :rvm_ruby_string, 'ruby-1.9.3@myapp'        # Or whatever env you want it to run in.
set :rvm_type, :system
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bundler is not part of standard capistrano recipe

use this answer [How do I manage bundled gems in a capistrano deployment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808891/how-do-i-manage-bundled-gems-in-a-capistrano-deployment)

Comment: Ya, I finally figured it out...this is the correct answer and unfortunately, to me anyway, not at all obvious from the documentation. Oh, and that correct answer is, btw, `require 'bundler/capistrano'` at top of `deploy.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same setup working, only my config also has this line:

```
set :rvm_path, '/usr/local/rvm'
```

and doesn't have the :rvm_type variable set.

Comment: Can you point me to documentation for setting the `rvm_path` variable directly? The documentation I found (link above) recommends setting *something* as so: `$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path']))`

Comment: I had to do some searching, but was able to find the `:rvm_path` variable in the [rvm source code](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/blob/master/lib/rvm/capistrano.rb#L26)